# ping|awk not responsive

Tags: linux, ping, awk

While trying [melodyping](https://twitter.com/#!/climagic/status/192314987694407680), I noticed that

```
ping <host> |awk '{print $1}'
```

takes about 30 seconds until the first line is actually displayed. Even though w/o piping to awk each ping is returned in about 35 msec.

What causes that delay?

Comment: Works fine for me. What do you get after 30 seconds?

Comment: @EranBen-Natan After those 30s I get a bulk of expected output, i. e. lines from `ping` with times around 35ms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead ;)

```
while true; do ping -c 1 <host> | awk '{print $1}'; done
```

Must be something about how `ping` terminates lines.

Comment: Or possibly a lack of flushing. (which is just unhygienic imo)

Comment: Nice work around. +1